# Any easy way to do a Find/Replace in all entries and fields?

Tags: ee2, control-panel

I know there is the Search & Replace functionality built into the control panel but I'm hoping to find a way to do this on all entries and fields without having to run it individually for each field. Has anyone else done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Another option: [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/find-replace) has a really nice Find & Replace that allows you to select multiple fields and even restrict by category, a replace preview, and replace log.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do that on the database side thru PHPMyAdmin or Sequel Pro or something like that. It goes without saying that that is dangerous so always make backups! But that would be by far the fastest way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

As Mark pointed out, you would need to do this in the database.  Here's a sample query you could use.  MAKE BACKUPS beforehand though!

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_1 = REPLACE(field_id_1,'string to find','string to replace');
```

You would need to update the 'field_id_1' with whatever field you're trying to do the find/replace on.